# How to create a new column for each value associated with a specific ID in SQL query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to extract information about certain people based on their ID and what job they've applied for. Each job has a specific ID and each person has a specific ID. You can ignore the join and from parts of the code below.

```
select distinct
person_id "Person ID", 
job_id "Job ID"

from
job_table
join application_table on job_id = app_jobID
join person_table on app_id = per_appID

order by person_id, job_id;
```

When I run code like this it returns a table like so

| Person ID | Job ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 142 |
| 1 | 631 |
| 2 | 108 |
| 3 | 135 |
| 3 | 213 |
| 3 | 534 |

I'm wondering how to change my code to make it look like this, with a different column for each job they've applied for. It varies how many jobs a person has applied for

| Person_ID | Job_ID1 | Job_ID2 | Job_ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 142 | 631 |  |
| 2 | 108 |  |  |
| 3 | 534 | 135 | 213 |

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please tag your DBMS product. From aliases, it seems Oracle. This seems a simple conditional aggregation.

Comment: Apologies, yes it's oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a ROW_NUMBER and then can do conditional aggregation on this column -

```
SELECT person_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN job_id ELSE NULL END) Job_ID1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN job_id ELSE NULL END) Job_ID2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN job_id ELSE NULL END) Job_ID3
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT person_id "Person ID",
                        job_id "Job ID"
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY person_id) RN
          FROM job_table
          JOIN application_table ON job_id = app_jobID
          JOIN person_table ON app_id = per_appID) 
 GROUP BY person_id
 ORDER BY person_id, job_id;
```

Comment: Hi, that's great but in the case of the actual data (which I can't share), a person could have applied for hundreds of jobs.

Comment: You can definitely go for dynamic pivot then else you have to hardcode 100 rows for this code to work